# Extracting the first month name encountered in a string column

Tags: python, pandas

given a column `summary`

```
summary
'Altemio C. Sanchez (born January 19, 1958) is a Puerto Rican serial killer'
'Alton Coleman (November 6, 1955 - April 26, 2002) was an American serial killer'
'Amelia Elizabeth Dyer (born Hobley; 1836 - 10 June 1896) was one of the most prolific serial killers'
'Amy Duggan "Sister" Archer-Gilligan (31 October 1873 - April 23, 1962) was a serial killer'
```

I'm trying to extract the month in which the person was born, it's OK if they dont have a birth month, but if they do have it, it needs to be extracted.

Right now I'm using numpy.where() to fill a new column if the pattern is found.

```
killers['month'] =  np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('january'),'01',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('february'),'02',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('march'),'03',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('april'),'04',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('may'),'05',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('june'),'06',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('july'),'07',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('august'),'08',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('september'),'09',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('october'),'10',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('november'),'11',
                    np.where(killers['summary'].astype(str).str.lower().str.contains('december'),'12', ''))))))))))))
```

But some death months (i.e. born in october, died in april) are overwriting the birth month in the `month` column

is there any way to keep the first found month exclusively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) (see comments):

```py
# Define a month mapper (name to number)
month_map = dict(zip(
    ['january','february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july',
     'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'],
    range(1,13)
))

# Extracting the first month name and map them to the correspondent number
killers['month'] = (df.summary.str.lower() # set strings to lower
 .str.findall('|'.join(month_map.keys())) # extract all available months
 .map(lambda x: x[0]) # Extract just the first one
 .map(month_map) # map them to its number
)
```

---

Note: This will only work if every string has at least one month available, otherwise it's gonna raise an `IndexError`. You can avoid it by change the fist `map` line to:

```
.map(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)>0 else np.nan)
```

where you'll get `NaN` for strings without any months.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make map return an int instead of a float?

Comment: You can add either `.astype(int)` or `.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())` to the chain (after the last `map` line).